# Internationalize webapp javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internationalization, gettext

I'm developing a webapp which consumes its own API to show the contents, and it's javascript through AJAX who does it.
When I worked with serverside processing (php) I used gettext, but now I don't know how to translate the strings generated with javascript.
How I can do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with use of **Gettext**, than use it's JS implementation

http://jsgettext.berlios.de/

And load your language catalogs via calling API and using `localStorage` as cache